# Multiple products to share the same stock/sku?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, inventory, stock

I have a WooCommerce web shop that offers interchangeable sandals.

These straps are compatible with multiple heels (categories) and so I need to show them in different places on my site with different product images, but as they are essentially the same physical item they need to be registered on the same SKU so they can share stock amount.

Does anybody have an idea for solving this problem?

If we can't do multiple products on the same SKU.
Mabe a product image that is path determined so it is only the product image that changes depending on which category the item is opened under.

Comment: Why not use a variable product and use a variation for each version that requires a different product image?

Comment: You see The heels are the categories, so I can't set the heel as a variation and every strap model has multiple colors, materials and sizes which I am using as attributes and variations

Comment: To clarify, a heel on its own is a product and a category, so under category 'X' there is the 'X' product (the heel) and a list of straps that are compatible with this 'X' product, let call them 'X1' - 'X8'. Now let's say that 'X2' and 'X4' are compatible with 'B'product (which is bothe a separate category and another heel) I'm trying to figure out how to show those straps on every compatible heel, as a complete shoe, each in its own category, does that make any sense? I've tried linking to my site so you could see what I'm talking about but LoicTheAztec deleted it.